# Jordan curve of infinite length

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry

I was thinking about Jordan curve with infinite length and Koch snowflake seems to be a valid answer intutively. Can anyone give mathematical proof for this?

Comment: Perhaps an Osgood curve would also fit your criteria? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osgood_curve

Answer (score 1):

This is quite simple if you define arc length sensibly. One definition of arc length is the supremum of the length of its polygonal approximations. Then you use the construction of the Koch snowflake as providing approximations.

You have $\gamma_j$ being a polygon and it's length is $(4/3)^j$ and $\gamma=\lim \gamma_j$ being the Koch snowflake.

Now we have that the corners of $\gamma_j$ being on $\gamma$ (since corners are preserved as $j\to\infty$. They also occur in correct order. So we have that the length of $\gamma$ must be at least $(4/3)^j$ for all $j$, which means that the length must be infinite.